# Create an alertdialog which include a list

Tags: java, list, radio-button, android-alertdialog

How can I make a list on AlertDialog which include some radiobuttons in that , and when I clicked on items of the AlertDialog , do something like toast .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Setup the alert builder
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Choose an animal");// add a radio button list
String[] animals = {"horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat"};
int checkedItem = 1; // cow
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(animals, checkedItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //Here you can implement Toast Message
    }
});
//Add OK and Cancel buttons
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //Handle when user clicks OK
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null); //Create and show the alert dialog
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Let me know if that helped :)

Comment: A question : I do that but i need some thing for exmaple this alertdialog include just an ok button at bottom|right and for instance 3 radio button in that and when you click on one of them , do the event and alertdialog close automatically?

Comment: Well, then just remove the line builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null); //Create and show the alert dialog to remove the Cancel button. To close alertDialog, just call dialog.dismiss() or dialog.close()

Comment: I have just a question : for example these radio buttons are : animals , humen , flowers . And I wanna give diffrent events to them , for instance when I clicked animals toast this : animals clicked . And when I clicked on flowers toast : flowers clicked and when humen clicked toast : humen clicked how can I do that sir?

Comment: In the setSingleChoiceItems onClick method, check the which variable. Like if(which == 0) {Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked on horse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

Comment: If I have helped you please upvote my answer and accept it as solution :) thank you

Comment: Thanks alot that was actually great